Expected value of a matrix = matrix of expected value?
I'm wondering about the following statement : the expectation of a matrix equals to the matrix of expectations.
For instance, let $A$ be a matrix of 4 random variables $W,X,Y,Z$, i.e., $A = \begin{bmatrix} W & X \\ Y & Z\end{bmatrix}$.
Then, we typically write that
$$E(A) = \begin{bmatrix} E[W] & E[X] \\ E[Y] & E[Z] \end{bmatrix}.$$
Is this always true? What if some/all of the R.V. are correlated ?

You're probably looking for a rigorous demonstration to check your intuition.  It helps to examine this situation abstractly and even more generally.
Suppose $A$ is a $Y$-valued random variable defined on a probability space $\Omega$ with sigma algebra $\mathfrak F$ and probability measure $\mathbb P$ where $Y$ is any real vector space with a sigma algebra $\mathfrak G.$  This means two things.  First, measurability means the pullback of any event $\mathcal E\in\mathfrak G$ is an event:
$$A^{*}(\mathcal E) = \{\omega\in\Omega\mid A(\omega)\in\mathcal E\} \in \mathfrak F.$$
Second, we can form finite real linear combinations of elements of $Y$ according to the usual algebraic rules.  This is necessary for defining expectation, because
$$E[A] = \int_\Omega A(\omega)\,\mathrm d\mathbb P(\omega)\in Y$$
is ultimately defined in terms of simple functions $A.$  These are finite $Y$-valued linear combinations of indicator functions, which is why $Y$ must be a vector space.
Let $\pi:Y\to\mathbb R$ be any measurable linear map (where $\mathbb R$ is endowed with its sigma algebra generated by Borel sets).  The measurability of $\pi$ implies the composition $\pi\circ A:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a random variable.  Its expectation is defined to be
$$E[\pi\circ A] = \int_\Omega \pi(A(\omega))\,\mathrm d\mathbb P(\omega) \in \mathbb R.$$
Because $\pi$ is linear, the linearity of the integral tells us

$$E[\pi\circ A] = \int_\Omega \pi(A(\omega))\,\mathrm d\mathbb P(\omega) = \pi\left(\int_\Omega A(\omega)\,\mathrm d\mathbb P(\omega)\right) = \pi(E[A]).$$

Take $Y$ to be a vector space of matrices of fixed dimension and let $\pi$ return a specific coordinate of a matrix.  These satisfy all the conditions in the foregoing analysis (it's an elementary exercise to show this) and the conclusion is that the expectation of a coordinate, $E[\pi\circ A],$ is the coordinate of the expectation, $\pi(E[A]),$ QED.

Although this is all trivial--it's just chasing the most basic definitions and properties of random variables, expectations, and integrals--the generality is useful.  For instance, it is immediate that the expectation of any finite collection of values of a stochastic process (such as a time series or spatial process) is found from the expectation of the process, regardless of any correlation structure that process might have.
Finally, a look back over this analysis shows that concepts of correlation or independence play no role.  This is one reason arguments based on expectations can be so elegant and simple.

Thank you @whuber for taking the time to answer. I truly appreciate it. What I seem to understand from your explanation is the importance of linearity. \mathbb{E} is a linear operator and therefore we find the answer to my question. However, were we to take say Cov operator, it's bi-linear (i.e. take Cov(A;B) we have it is linear when fixing one R.V.). Would that reasoning still hold ? That is, Cov(matrix) = matrix of Cov ? What does "holding one constant" would mean in a matrix setting ?
I hope this is clear. Thank you again for your answer.

Could you clarify what you mean by "Cov(matrix)"? One would imagine you are thinking of a matrix-valued random variable, say with $m$ rows and $n$ columns. Those values are in a vector space of $mn$ dimensions and the covariance of any such random variable would be a $mn\times mn$ matrix.  Unless $m=1$ or $n=1,$ there's no way to make any sense of equating that to the original $m\times n$ matrix.

@MaximusGlad, I don't think linearity of expectation operator is the key assumption here. It's the assumption that vector is used to represent linear combinations that is important. that's why the "proof" seems to be tautological to me

Always true.
The answer by @Ben Bolker is less assertive in tone, but it gives the critical aspect - that a matrix is defined as an element-wise collection, hence the expected value operator is applied to each element separately and hence any statistical connection of each element does not enter the picture. This is analogous to the additivity property $E(X + Y) = E(X) + (E(Y)$ irrespective of whether $(X,Y)$ are correlated.
But $E(AB) \neq E(A)E(B)$ in general because here, you may get products of correlated variables that may not allow decomposing the expected value.

Thank you Alecos for taking the time to answer !

I don't know about the formal definition, but according to some reasonably sensible-looking references, e.g.

https://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Matrices.html
http://www.statpower.net/Content/313/Lecture%20Notes/MatrixExpectedValue.pdf
https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/04%3A_Expected_Value/4.08%3A_Expected_Value_and_Covariance_Matrices

this is indeed the definition of the expected value of a matrix. It makes sense, given that the sum of matrices is their elementwise sum ($\mathbf X + \mathbf Y = (x_{ij} + y_{ij})$), and that dividing by the total number of matrices (scalar multiplication by $1/n$) is also defined elementwise ($\mathbf X/n = (x_{ij}/n)$), that we don't have to worry about the relationships among the elements ...

Thank you Ben for taking the time to answer and for the references. They seem to be very useful.

That is a common convention in vector notation of multivariate statistics. It's not a theorem to prove or an axiom to state. It's just a convenient way to manipulate random vectors and matrices.

Yes, it can be viewed as a mere matter of notation.  But it's more than that and it really is a theorem deserving of proof.

+1 to both the answer and the comment.

This is always true, and follows from the linearity of expectation, i.e. the fact that for any random variables $A$ and $B$, $$\mathbb E[A+B] = \mathbb E[A] + \mathbb E[B],$$ even if $A$ and $B$ are not independent, and also $$\mathbb E[c A] = c \,\mathbb E[A]$$ for any constant $c$.

As a corollary, if $A = c_1 X_1 + c_2 X_2 + \dots + c_n X_n$, where $X_1$, $X_2$, $\dots$, $X_n$ are any (possibly non-independent) random variables and $c_1$, $c_2$, $\dots$, $c_n$ are any constants, then $$\mathbb E[A] = c_1 \mathbb E[X_1] + c_2 \mathbb E[X_2] + \dots + c_n \mathbb E[X_n].$$

In particular, let $$A =
\begin{bmatrix} W & X \\ Y & Z \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} W +
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} X +
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} Y +
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} Z.
$$
Then, by the linearity of expectation, $$\mathbb E[A] =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \mathbb E[W] +
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \mathbb E[X] +
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \mathbb E[Y] +
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \mathbb E[Z] =
\begin{bmatrix} \mathbb E[W] & \mathbb E[X] \\ \mathbb E[Y] & \mathbb E[Z] \end{bmatrix}.
$$

And yes, this is essentially whuber's answer with less background detail. However, I feel that sometimes excessive detail can obscure the key point, which is the linearity of $\mathbb E[\cdot]$.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. Suppose $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is measurable and $E(\|X\|) < \infty$. The simplest approach to define $E(X) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is to define $E(X)_{jk} := E(X_{jk})$.
A more robust approach is to use the Bochner integral, which works to integrate any measurable $Y : \Omega \to V$ with $E(\|Y\|) < \infty$, where $V$ is a separable Banach space. The map $\pi_{jk} : \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\pi_{jk}A = A_{jk}$ is a continuous linear map, so it can be interchanged with the Bochner integral: $$E(X)_{jk} = \pi_{jk}E(X) = E(\pi_{jk}X) = E(X_{jk}).$$
The reason I say this approach is more robust is it allows $V$ to be infinite-dimensional.

This is a version of the argument in @whuber's answer

@kjetilbhalvorsen Whuber's answer does not define $E(X)$ for vector valued $X$, and does not prove why expectation commutes with (continuous) linear maps. It is totally unsatisfactory in my opinion.

If you think so, you can ask as a comment below his answer. cc @whuber
